# I have uninstalled Lord of the Rings online but desktop icons are still present

Tags: wine, .desktop

I have installed the game with the help of WINE and removed it with it's own installer but the icon is still visible.

The icon is still there in the app drawer. Whenever I click on that symbol it's showing `path not found`

How do I remove the icon?

[image: Picture of Dash]

Comment: What is the output of `grep -r "Lord" /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: Yes, that about sums it up! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to rearrange your question bevor I understood it. There are two places where the desktop information resides:
`/home/<user>/.local/share/applications`

-where "<user>" is your user...  Note that ".local" is a hidden folder and might not be visible in your filemanager. Then you should change the visibility to "show hidden files".

If they are not to be found at the location above look at:

`/usr/share/applications`

Go into the first location and check if there are any "desktop" files that you mentioned and delete them.

The second location is not in user space. That means you might so use a terminal to delete them:

`sudo rm /usr/share/applications/<filename>.desktop`